# what does this mean in php: ->

Tags: php, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In, PHP, what is the “->” operator called and how do you say it when reading code out loud?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588149/in-php-what-is-the-operator-called-and-how-do-you-say-it-when-reading-code)

->  I can't seem to find it anywhere:  This operator ->

Comment: Why the downvotes? It's a legitimate question that's hard to search.

Comment: Agreed.  Do a search in Stack Overflow for 'php ->' and only this question looks immediately related.  If you don't know the term for a symbol or group of symbols, how can you expect someone to figure it out without straight up asking?

Comment: Yet still you elected to close it, NullUserException?

Comment: @David It's a legitimate question, but it's also a duplicate. You close duplicates, and downvote bad questions. The two are not in any way related.

Comment: actually, i searched for it and nothing came up.  it just comes up with search operators.  I'm a little new w/ stackoverflow so you'll have to forgive me for the dup