# PHP: What is "->" and "=>"?

Tags: php, syntax

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

I've been programming with PHP for a bit now, but every once in a while I run across these two expressions:

```
->
=>
```

What are these and what do they mean/do? I don't even know what to call them in order to find out...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588149/in-php-what-is-the-operator-called-and-how-do-you-say-it-when-reading-code

Comment: As for `->`, see [what does this mean in php: ->](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3910147/what-does-this-mean-in-php).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`->` is for accessing attributes and methods of an object:

```
class myClass
{
    public $anAttribute = 'hey this is my attribute';

    public function myMethod()
    {
        return 'this is my method';
    }

}

$class = new myClass();
echo $class->anAttribute;
echo $class->myMethod();
```

`=>` is used in two places. This can be while instantiating an array manually or dynamically in an `foreach`-statement:

```
// Manually instantiated:
$myArray = new array('fruit' => 'apple', 'meat' => 'sausage');
echo $myArray['fruit'];
echo $myArray['meat'];

// Dynamic in foreach
foreach($myArray AS $key => $value)
{
    echo "myArray['$key'] is $value";
}
```

Answer (score 5):

`->` is used to access instance attributes of objects. It is the equivalent to the `.` syntax in many other languages (C, C++, Python, Javascript).

```
$myclass->my_instance_var;
$myclass->my_instance_method();
```

`=>` is used to map keys to values in associative arrays. It is the equivalent of `:` in a mapping in Python and Javascript.

```
$arr = Array("Hello" => "World", "Foo" => "Bar");
```

Comment: Do you have an example of both? I'm not seeing why I would need to use them.

Comment: _associative arrays_  this is not a restriction you can use with numerical index array as well

Comment: @Shakti when you specify numerical indices, those are associative arrays. Technically, in PHP, all arrays are associative, but there's a special case where keys are assigned for you. @dcolumbus you'd use the first if you write or use classes; you'd use the seconds if you use associative arrays.

Answer (score 5):

`->` this symbol is used to refer the property or method of object

```
$obj->age=25;
$obj->setAge();
```

`=>` this symbol is used to assign values in array

```
$array=array('age'=>25,'name'=>'test');
$array=array(10=>20, 30=>50);
```

Comment: So in PHP, do I have to use the "->" in order to call a method within a class? In ActionScript, all I have to do is: obj.function();

Comment: @dcolumbus: Yes, But the static method are exception in this case they can be called with `classname::statcimethod()`

Answer (score 1):

They are both operators.

The => is an assigment operator for arrays, assigning values to a named key.
Have a look at http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php

The -> is an accessor so if you have a class Foo with a variable Bar you would access that using the -> operator:

`// Get value of Bar
$value = $fooInstance->Bar`

Basically the -> operator is similar to the "." in Java and C#