# What does "->" mean?

Tags: php, syntax

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)
>   [In, PHP, what is the “->” operator called and how do you say it when reading code out loud?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588149/in-php-what-is-the-operator-called-and-how-do-you-say-it-when-reading-code)

This is a really newbie question, so apologies in advance, but I've seen `->` used several times in example code, but I can't seem to find any explanation in online tutorials for what it does. (Mainly because Google ignores it as a search term - doh!)

Here's an example that confuses me:

```
<?php
class customException extends Exception
{
public function errorMessage()
{
//error message
$errorMsg = 'Error on line '.$this->getLine().' in '.$this->getFile()
.': <b>'.$this->getMessage().'</b> is not a valid E-Mail address';
return $errorMsg;
}
}

$email = "someone@example.com";

try
  {
  //check if
  if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === FALSE)
    {
    //throw exception if email is not valid
    throw new customException($email);
    }
  //check for "example" in mail address
  if(strpos($email, "example") !== FALSE)
    {
    throw new Exception("$email is an example e-mail");
    }
  }

catch (customException $e)
  {
  echo $e->errorMessage();
  }

catch(Exception $e)
  {
  echo $e->getMessage();
  }
?>
```

What is going on in lines such as `echo $e->errorMessage();`? It looks like its passing the variable `$e` to the function `errorMessage()`, but if so, why not just do it in the more traditional way?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: It's not a duplicate of either of those two things, but thanks anyway.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3037526/where-we-use-object-operator-in-php) that second possible duplicate was incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not a scope resolution operator. `::` (also called Paamayim Nekudotayim) is the scope resolution operator, see [the manual](http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php).

No, it is not a function. This is object oriented programming, so the correct term is `method`.

No, it is not a property. Again, it's a `method`.

I am not aware of any terminology for the `->` construct. It is used to either call methods or to access properties on an *instance* of a class. On an object. I suppose you could refer to it as the "instance operator".

In your specific case it's a method call. The `errorMessage` method is being called on your `$e` object, which is an instance of the `customException` class.

Comment: Apparently its official name is "object operator".

Answer (score 4):

It's used in object oriented programming to denote object->property

`echo "$foo->bar"` would echo the bar property of $foo

Answer (score 2):

`$e` is an object.

That object has the function `errorMessage()`

Therefore you are calling `$e`'s function