# PHP Object Syntax

Tags: php, object

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In, PHP, what is the “->” operator called and how do you say it when reading code out loud?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588149/in-php-what-is-the-operator-called-and-how-do-you-say-it-when-reading-code)

Could someone help with a simple query we have? Whilst we use it every minute of every day, we have no idea what "->" is called in PHP when accessing object methods etc. (eg $this->class->method()  ).

We know what is does but when discussing it all we call it is "arrow thing".

Comment: ah. true. sorry for answering :)

Answer (score 4):

It's called the object operator.

Comment: I did search but the search box couldn't get to grips with "->". Anyway thanks for answering, never apologise for helping someone!