# Arrows within variables?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In, PHP, what is the "->" operator called and how do you say it when reading code out loud?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588149/in-php-what-is-the-operator-called-and-how-do-you-say-it-when-reading-code)

This is the second question I've asked about the following tutorial:

http://www.allsyntax.com/tutorials/PHP/24/Building-a-Comments-Script/2.php

I'm very new to PHP / MySQL so I'm just trying to get familiar with it. I need to know what the arrows mean / do in the second code-box down the page...

e.g.

```
"'.htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($info2->subject)).'"
```

(The arrow between `$info2` and `subject`).

Comment: SO is not a personal PHP tutorial.

Comment: you should seriously go into http://php.net/manual/en/ and read the `Language Reference` section

Comment: Yeah, I get it - should I delete this question or something?

Comment: @Dan: No, just do some research please before asking similar ones!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The arrow means that subject is a member variable of the object represented by $info2. The arrow -> is object notation. Array notation would be $info2['subject'] for comparison.

Comment: Thanks for the comparison with array notation - that's something I've been over. I'm not familiar with objects.

Answer (score 1):

The arrow is used to access a member of an object instance(This holds since PHP5). Prior to PHP5 it was also possible to access static members of a class.

There is a good explanation here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php

Answer (score 0):

`->` is [the object operator](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php).

Buy yourself a good PHP book. Stack Overflow is not a tutorial, and web tutorials will *not* teach you PHP properly.

Also, keep the PHP manual bookmarked. Ensure that you have read it, all, at least three times before asking further questions about PHP syntax here.

Comment: I've already ordered one - I'm just looking up tuts in the meantime. I'll look through the PHP manual. I'd gone through the operators through a tutorial somewhere but this one wasn't mentioned.

Comment: @Dan: Put the "tuts" down. They will lead you astray. Go do something else until your book arrives. :)