# PHP5 Object-Oriented Programming operators

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the “->” PHP operator called and how do you say it when reading code out loud?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588149/what-is-the-php-operator-called-and-how-do-you-say-it-when-reading-code-out)
>   [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

What is the name of the sign `->` in php5 ?

Comment: Blockquote did you already look in the documentation?

Comment: Read the PHP documentation PLEASE. [OOP Basics](http://php.net/oop5)

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588149/what-is-the-php-operator-called-and-how-do-you-say-it-when-reading-code-out

Comment: The answer was shorter than both your answers chastising them. I think the hard part is the symbol is hard to search for via Google etc.

Comment: THis guy made a survey: http://www.robert-gonzalez.com/2009/03/04/php-operators-double-and-single-arrow/

Answer (score 0):

It is called the object notation operator