# In PHP, does => have a name?

Tags: php

I only see it referred by the symbol itself but never named, but I'm in school, learning it, and my instructor doesn't know if it has a name either.  He calls it "array assignment operator," which seems a bit long to me.

Comment: More broadly it's called "[fat comma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fat_comma)".

Comment: @Fred -ii- Not a dupe.

Comment: @Boann If it's not a dupe, then [read what this guy said...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33270905/in-php-does-have-a-name?noredirect=1#comment54343236_33270937). Therefore, the answer should have been a comment.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I don't follow your logic at all.

Comment: @Boann I quote: *"Thanks ;-) I googled 'php operator names', found [this so question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588149/what-is-the-php-operator-called-and-how-do-you-say-it-when-reading-code-out), and clicked on the T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in the answer ;-) – Kenney 14 hours ago"* - the guy posted an answer based on that link. In my view, that constitutes as a duplicate. If not, then the answer should be flagged as not an answer.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I guess it's not worth arguing, as we agree on the fact of the answer, but we disagree on a point of philosophy: whether a Q/A needs to justify its right to be (exclusionism), or if someone needs to justify its right to not be (inclusionism).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PHP itself](http://php.net/manual/en/tokens.php) calls it the "double arrow".

Comment: Fantastic!  I googled for like an hour trying to find the answer to this!  You're the best.  I don't have enough reputation to vote you publicly, but I'll upvote you once I have enough.  lol

Comment: Thanks ;-) I googled 'php operator names', found [this so question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588149/what-is-the-php-operator-called-and-how-do-you-say-it-when-reading-code-out), and clicked on the `T_OBJECT_OPERATOR` in the answer ;-)

Comment: @ChrisStanley Since this is your question, you can accept the answer as well.