# Can you use an arrow operator with $_POST and $_GET php?

Tags: php

All examples I can find on the internet seem to show using the indexing operator for `$_GET` and `$_POST`.

For example,
I would think you could write:

```
<?php
    echo $_GET->parameterName;
?>
```

instead of

```
<?php
    echo $_GET['parameterName'];
?>
```

I get this error when I try the first piece of code:

```
NOTICE Trying to get property of non-object on line number 2
```

Comment: No, that is not possible. `$_GET` is not an object. it is an array.

Comment: No, because the global variables `$_GET` and `$_POST` are an array. You can cast it to an object though.

Comment: `->` is an [operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2588149/1415724), so you can't use that method. This besides the other comments above.

Comment: Strange that you would ask this question.  Did you try it? What were your results? And why would you think that it was available?

Comment: just for curiosity sake, what did this `echo $_GET->parameterName;` give you? please turn on `error_reporting(E_ALL);`. That's how you'll learn

Comment: if you really hated yourself and the other devs you might ever work with, you could `$_GET = (object) $_GET;` and then it would work. terrible idea though, its only neat for the sake of it.

Comment: NO: you cannot access property of non-object. 
Note: it is not recommended to use global variables directly. You can wrap it into some custom object, introduce sanitation, validation etc.  - this will make your code more readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO, you should not directly cast it to an object, instead you should use [ArrayObject](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php), which will allow you to access both as an array or as an object.

```
<?php
$_GET['parameterName'] = 'foo';

$_GET = new ArrayObject($_GET);
$_GET->setFlags(ArrayObject::STD_PROP_LIST | ArrayObject::ARRAY_AS_PROPS);

echo $_GET->parameterName.PHP_EOL;
echo $_GET['parameterName'].PHP_EOL;

foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
    echo $key.' => '.$value.PHP_EOL;
}
```

https://3v4l.org/FmYIQ

**Result:**

```
foo
foo
parameterName => foo
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cast `$_GET` as object:

```
$getObj = (object) $_GET;
```

Maybe this is also working:

```
$_GET = (object) $_GET;
```